# Enlarging images using CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am using the css and Javascript method to enlarge the image in a page..
I used some code s which didn't give me a correct way..

Seeking help and I have given my fiddle link below

My Css is

```
 #demo {
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 120px;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 10px;
                z-index: 3;
            }

                #demo img {
                    border: none;
                    width: 100px;
                    height: 100px;
                    border: 5px solid #f4f4f4;
                    z-index: 3;
                }

            #enlarge_images {
                ;
                display: none;
                border: 5px solid #f4f4f4;
                z-index: 100;
            }
```

I tried this Fiddle **[CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/shyamsundar055/jujgE/)**

Comment: Perhapse you'd be kind enough to explain why this isn't what you wanted, and what actually you _did_ want.

Comment: what's that ; after ---> #enlarge_images { ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this Fiddle

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jujgE/1/)

Not exactly sure what your javascript did or was meant to do but check this out .

CSS

```
 #demo img{
     width: 100px;     
     padding: 10px;
     z-index: 3;
 }
 #demo img:hover {
     border: 5px solid #f4f4f4;
    transform: scale(2.8);
      -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
     z-index: 3;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="demo" >
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
</div>
```